# Voltage Mode Buck Converter Output Voltage

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, buck

I am trying to design a simple buck converter. But it doesn't work as expected. Output voltage should be 19V but it is very close to input with value 48.5V. Also there is a problem with pwm generator.
If anyone could help,I will appreciate for it.Thanks.

[image]

With this configuration pwm generator (comparator LT1001) doesn't work well, but seperately it works.
[image]

And the Output:
[image]

feedback goes through differential opamp:
[image]

Comment: For a start, the MOSFET is connected backward, no flyback diode?

Comment: You never turn the FET off for a start, plus it's reversed, so the body diode conducts. Plus yu have almost certainly exceeded its Vgs(max) and destroyed it.

Comment: where's your diode ?1 (between the common tap of mosfet & inductor and Gnd)

Comment: sorry, I should have removed diode accidentally. I edited the results

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- The MOSFET has an internal parasitic diode that will always cause conduction from the input voltage to the output voltage.
- The MOSFET's gate will be destroyed by ineffective gate voltage control

I'm stopping counting the faults now!

Comment: More things: 1. Why R7 and R8? Your fb node is set for a ~5/31 ratio to your output, so 19V you'd expect ~3V at the fb node. With R7 and R8 your reference is 1.5V so you'd regulate to only ~9.3V. 2. Please add some compensation to U3, for pure voltage mode control you need a Type 3 compensator. 3. Your ramp looks too triangley, you want it more saw-toothy (these are the technical terms). 4. You need V+ to be higher than V1 or else the NMOS FET you chose won't turn on. Idk if LTSpice has a high side gate driver, but use that also.